# Execute a function when session expires using client-sessions (node.js)

Tags: javascript, node.js, session, express

I'm trying to figure out how to execute a function when a session expires using express and the [client-sessions](https://www.npmjs.com/package/client-sessions) package in my node.js project.

I have an array where I store when logging in the active users usernames. 
My script executes a function when they log out to remove the users username from the Array.

So far so good.

But I don't get it how to do this when a session expires by itself.

What I basically want to do is to be able to count the active users using the arrays length.

I'm searching now several hours for an answer but can't find anything.

Is there any way to do this or am I on the wrong path?

ps. Sorry for my english

pps. Ask me if you need to see the code, I didn't add it because it's almost the same as the one on the packages documentation

Comment: Hey, did you ever find your answer?